# Write Text on Border in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

Does any one knows how to do this in the XAML? (Check the picture bellow plz)
[image]
I tried to search it but I did not have the right key words to do so, Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for a [`GroupBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx):

```
<GroupBox Header="Quick Links">
    <!-- content -->
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer!
I am new to WPF and XAML, so I am learning

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by using WPF's `GroupBox` control.

Just set the `Header` property to the text you want.